# Improper variable python

Tags: python, variables

A small section of my program. A and B are suppose to be different but come out the same. A = B even after changing. Any suggestions.

```
def reveal_board(location1, location2, a):
    b = a
    for char in board:
        if char == board[location1 - 1]:
            b[location1 - 1] = char
        if char == board[location2 - 1]:
            b[location2 - 1] = char
        else:
            b = b
    print_board(b)
    if board[location1 - 1] == board[location2 - 1]:
        return b
    else:
        return a
```

Comment: What *is* `a`? A `dict` I suppose...?

Comment: and what is `board`? Try to create a minimal example that displays the behaviour you're confused about.

Comment: board is a list, and a is the same size as board just filled with "*". this is only a fragment of my program.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `a` and `b` are a more complex object such as a list or a dictionary, you're not actually making a copy of `a` when assigning `b = a`. This merely makes `a` and `b` both point to the same object. If you then modify `b`, you are also modifying `a` and vice versa.

If you want to make a copy, consider something like `b = list(a)` or `b = dict(a)`. Or, more generally:

```
import copy
b = copy.copy(a)
```

or even

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

to make a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html).

Comment: It doesn't look like you need a deep copy, so it's better to just use `b = a[:]`

Comment: @TomKarzes why do you think `b = a[:]` is preferable over `b = list(a)` or `b = copy.copy(a)`? Don't optimise at this level.

Comment: @Joost if it's built into the language, and avoids loading a package you don't need, then it's pretty much always preferable.  You should only load a package if you need it for something that isn't immediately available in the language.  Using the list constructor is ok, but using copy is excessive.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `b = a` isn't copying `a`, but is merely copying a reference to the same list that `a` references.  To actually copy it, replace the assignment with:

```
b = a[:]
```

That will create a "shallow" copy of `a` and is simpler and faster than using `copy`.

Also, I suggest getting rid of the self-assignment of `b` to itself.  That doesn't make sense.  You can just delete that and the `else` above it:

```
else:
    b = b
```